# error in else block for directory copy

Tags: java, if-statement

I cannot for the life of me figure out what i am missing here.  I am getting an error with the else block. I have tried all variation of brackets but cannot seem to get it to work.  I need some fresh eyes to spot my mistake!  Any ideas?

```
 public static void makeCopies (File srcFolder, File destDirectory)throws Exception
{

    if (srcFolder.isDirectory())

   {

    destDirectory.mkdir();
    System.out.println("Directory copied from" +srcFolder + " to " +destDirectory);

   }

    String files[] = srcFolder.list();

    for (String file : files)

   {
    File srcFile = new File(srcFolder, file);
    File destFile = new File(destDirectory, file);
    //recursive copy
    makeCopies(srcFolder, destDirectory);
   }


 else {


   FileInputStream sourceStream = new FileInputStream(srcFolder);
   FileOutputStream destStream = new FileOutputStream(destDirectory);

    // use an integer to transfer data between files
   int transfer;

    // tell the user what is happening
   System.out.println("begining file copy:");
   System.out.println("\tcopying " + srcFolder);
   System.out.println("\tto      " + destDirectory);

    // read a byte, checking for end of file (-1 is returned by read at EOF)
   while ((transfer = sourceStream.read()) != -1) {

        // write a byte 
        destStream.write(transfer);

    } // end while

    // close file streams 
    sourceStream.close();
    destStream.close();

    System.out.println("File copy complete.");

}
```

Comment: `}else`  ....... your if block finish, then you write code and then you made a for loop, and then an else that has no if connected

Comment: The else block isn't connected to the corresponding if block

Comment: as it is I get if without else.  If i try }else{ i get illegal start of type..

Comment: @jpw  not sure why.  Thought my syntax was correct.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @MichaelJames Others have already pointed out the error and solution in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have all this chunk of code between the end of your `if` block and `else` block:

```
if
{
  ...
}

String files[] = srcFolder.list();
for (String file : files)
{
    File srcFile = new File(srcFolder, file);
    File destFile = new File(destDirectory, file);
    //recursive copy
    makeCopies(srcFolder, destDirectory);
}

else
{
  ...
}
```

this is not the right structure for if statement in java (or any C-like language for that matter).

it has to be this way:

```
if(condition) {
 ....
} else {
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing your braces on the else block nor on the method block.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` isn't attached to any `if`.  Assuming it's supposed to be the `else` for the `if` at the top of the method, just move the `else {` line up, immediately after you end your `if` block.

```
if (srcFolder.isDirectory())
{
   destDirectory.mkdir();
   System.out.println("Directory copied from" +srcFolder + " to " +destDirectory);
}
else {  // Move it here

   String files[] = srcFolder.list();
```

Or, if the code starting with `String files[] = srcFolder.list();` (immediately after the current end if the `if` block) is meant to be part of the `if`, then move the closing `if` `}` down to the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is outside of your `if` block, so the `else` you've written is seemingly part of the `for` loop instead. You're also missing a closing `}` for the `else` block.

What you have now:

```
if(){

}

for(){

}

else{
    // this isn't attached to the if block...
}
```

what you should have:

```
if(){
    // for loop can go here
}else{
    // or here
}
```